# How to Compare Values in Array

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, arrays

If you have a string of "1,2,3,1,5,7" you can put this in an array or hash table or whatever is deemed best.

How do you determine that all value are the same? In the above example it would fail but if you had "1,1,1" that would be true.

Comment: Where is the "Please do my homework" tag?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done nicely using lambda expressions.

For an array, named `arr`:

```
var allSame = Array.TrueForAll(arr, x => x == arr[0]);
```

For an list (`List<T>`), named `lst`:

```
var allSame = lst.TrueForAll(x => x == lst[0]);
```

And for an iterable (`IEnumerable<T>`), named `col`:

```
var first = col.First();
var allSame = col.All(x => x == first);
```

Note that these methods don't handle empty arrays/lists/iterables however. Such support would be trivial to add however.

Comment: @Martin: It isn't clear in the question whether that's a requirement or not. Of course, it would be very simple to support.

Comment: Linq is not an option for this project unfortunately

Comment: @Jon: First method (for arrays) doesn't require LINQ though. :)

Answer (score 6):

Iterate through each value, store the first value in a variable and compare the rest of the array to that variable. The instant one fails, you know all the values are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like...

```
string numArray = "1,1,1,1,1";
return numArrray.Split( ',' ).Distinct().Count() <= 1;
```

Comment: Linq is not an option for this project unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I think using `List<T>.TrueForAll` would be a slick approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not as efficient as a simple loop (as it always processes all items even if the result could be determined sooner), but:

```
if (new HashSet<string>(numbers.Split(',')).Count == 1) ...
```